# A webcomic about a mostly ocean world

Tags: story-identification, robots, webcomics

Recently, I’ve been having vague memories of a webcomic I read once, but I just can’t remember the name of it.

What I do remember is that its setting is in a world that is mostly underwater and that the characters use what I can best describe as aquatic mechs. There are also fish people, but what I remember the most is that one of the main characters is a girl with prosthetic limbs, since she was either born without them or was involved in an accident.

Comment: One of these, perhaps; https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OceanPunk

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Webcomic/Redd has the armless girl with prosthetics, but I don't remember mechs being a major factor. Target, she fights Kaiju who endanger shipping vessels.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for Planet Ripple, I think the main character is Minnow.

From the blurb on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35099102-planet-ripple):

> Minnow is a girl with disabilities born into a world gone down the drain. She is on the autism spectrum and **has four stumps, needing prosthetic limbs** to get around. For thousands of years the world has remained completely flooded, a floating blue marble in a black sea. When new land does finally appear, when what were once mountaintops in our time begin poking through the surface again to become islands, the **people of the world are ready to emerge from their submarines** and explore their new home... but this prospect may be too good to be true. **Also, we have mermaids. Sorta.**